How can I get a popup lov column to show the dropdown arrow indicator in an interactive grid?
I have an interactive grid and one of the columns is a popup lov. By default it just shows the value with no drop down arrow indicator.  When i click into it, it shows.  How can I get the entire column cells to show the indicator?  It shows if it is set up as a page item, but not in an interactive grid.

I want this:

